AES GCM Java BouncyCastle decryption fails second time
Using the below lines of code for Encrypting and Decrypting using BouncyCastle for decrypting data received from a 3rd party source based on C. First encryption and decryption works fine(basis the initial key and iv shared by the 3rd party which they have asked to use through out the session), second encryption and decryption fails.. mostly because I am using the same IV again if you notice. Looking for what might be the logic for the new IV creation and how am i supposed to send it to the 3rd party (if i do not send it, how can they decrypt without knowing the created IV)
public byte[] encrypt(byte[] plainBytes) {
        byte[] encryptedBytes = new byte[0];
        try {
            GCMBlockCipher cipher = new GCMBlockCipher(new AESFastEngine());
            AEADParameters parameters =
                    new AEADParameters(new KeyParameter(key), MacBitSize, iv);

            cipher.init(true, parameters);

            encryptedBytes = new byte[cipher.getOutputSize(plainBytes.length)];
            int retLen = cipher.processBytes
                    (plainBytes, 0, plainBytes.length, encryptedBytes, 0);
            cipher.doFinal(encryptedBytes, retLen);
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException |
                 IllegalStateException | DataLengthException |
                 InvalidCipherTextException ex) {
            System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
        }
        System.arraycopy(aad, 0, encryptedBytes, plainBytes.length, 16);
        byte[] final_encr = new byte[plainBytes.length];
        System.arraycopy(encryptedBytes, 0, final_encr, 0, plainBytes.length);
        return final_encr;
    }

    public byte[] decrypt(byte[] encryptedBytes) {
        byte[] plainBytes = new byte[0];
        try {
            GCMBlockCipher cipher = new GCMBlockCipher(new AESFastEngine());
            AEADParameters parameters =
                    new AEADParameters(new KeyParameter(key), MacBitSize, iv);

            cipher.init(false, parameters);
            cipher.processAADBytes(aad, 0, aad.length);
            plainBytes = new byte[encryptedBytes.length];
            int retLen = cipher.processBytes
                    (encryptedBytes, 0, encryptedBytes.length, plainBytes, 0);
            retLen += cipher.processBytes(aad, 0, aad.length, plainBytes, retLen);
            retLen += cipher.doFinal(plainBytes, retLen);
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException | IllegalStateException |
                 DataLengthException | InvalidCipherTextException ex) {
            System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
        }
        return plainBytes;
    }


Have tried to replace the last four digits of the iv and increase it incrementally
Tried C JNI library implementaion
Other libraries like kalium, JCE.. didn't work

Methodology provided by third party in the doc
For symmetric encryption/decryption methodology –
Encryption:
Initialization →
void encrypt_EVP_aes_256_cbc_init(EVP_CIPHER_CTX ** ctx, unsigned char * key,
    unsigned char * iv) {
    if (!( * ctx = EVP_CIPHER_CTX_new()))
        handleErrors();

    if (1 != EVP_EncryptInit_ex( * ctx, EVP_aes_256_gcm(), NULL, key, iv))
        handleErrors();
}

Encryption →
void encrypt(EVP_CIPHER_CTX * ctx, unsigned char * plaintext, int plaintext_len,
    unsigned char * ciphertext, int * ciphertext_len) {
    int len;

    if (1 != EVP_EncryptUpdate(ctx, ciphertext, & len, plaintext, plaintext_len))
        handleErrors();
    * ciphertext_len = len;
}

Decryption:
Initialization→
void decrypt_EVP_aes_256_cbc_init(EVP_CIPHER_CTX ** ctx, unsigned char * key,
    unsigned char * iv) {
    if (!( * ctx = EVP_CIPHER_CTX_new()))
        handleErrors();

    if (1 != EVP_DecryptInit_ex( * ctx, EVP_aes_256_gcm(), NULL, key, iv))
        handleErrors();
}

Decryption→
int decrypt(EVP_CIPHER_CTX * ctx, unsigned char * ciphertext, int ciphertext_len,
    unsigned char * plaintext, int * plaintext_len) {
    int len;

    if (1 != EVP_DecryptUpdate(ctx, plaintext, & len, ciphertext, ciphertext_len))
        handleErrors();
    * plaintext_len = len;
}

Note –

The ones highlighted in bold are OpenSSL library functions.
plaintext is the actual message buffer.
ciphertext is the encrypted message buffer.


Talk to the other party on how the IV is handled. Using the same IV twice will make your plaintext very vulnerable against attack. You should not use Bouncy here; the standard provider will use AES-NI and will therefore be much faster and more secure. The issue is not with the library or code, it is how the IV is handled by both parties, and we don't know anything about the other party.

@MaartenBodewes this is what is mentioned in the doc..
For symmetric encryption/decryption methodology – Encryption→ void encrypt_EVP_aes_256_gcm_init(EVP_CIPHER_CTX **ctx, unsigned char *key,
unsigned char *iv) Encryption→void encrypt(EVP_CIPHER_CTX *ctx, unsigned char *plaintext, int plaintext_len,
unsigned char *ciphertext, int *ciphertext_len)
Decryption -> void decrypt_EVP_aes_256_cbc_init(EVP_CIPHER_CTX **ctx, unsigned char *key,
unsigned char *iv).. decrypt
Note:

OpenSSL library functions.
plaintext is actual message buffer.
ciphertext is encrypted message buffer.


Reading code is very tricky in comments, please [edit] the question and add it in! We can then remove these two comments.

@MaartenBodewes updated question with the details mentioned in the document

Thanks for updating the question. I see you've already tried incrementing the IV / nonce. I'm not sure if you did that for the correct bytes or in the correct way of course. In the end how the IV is established is up to the creator of the protocol, so I'm pretty sure that's where the error is. By the way, I'm not sure why you would want to wrap every call to OpenSSL with its own method.

Wait are you mixing CBC and GCM code? Are you just picking various encryption / decryption methods from the internet and trying to use that? Are you processing AAD bytes as if they are ciphertext? What the heck are you doing?

since there is no logic mentioned on how to increment iv, i've tried to do it using various methods available over the internet (hit and trial) assuming one of them would be the one which is implemented by the openssl library internally which has been provided in the doc.. without using aad, i was able to decrypt but it was partial decryption which was incorrect as understood in the decrypted response.. with processing of aad, I was able to decrypt the complete packet accurately as expected.. again this is for the first encryption and decryption.. same didn't work for the second ones

I’m voting to close this question because it currently mixes different modes of operation, shows clear misunderstanding about how to use AAD, requires information about IV handling that is in control of a third party and in general cannot be solved by the SO users for that reason.

Maybe this would be a great time to use e.g. chatgpt; as you can see you'd still need quite a bit of patience to get great code from it, but for these kind of simple conversions it can be a useful tool.

Take a look at the parts of the encryption and decryption:

You need the IV data (12 bytes for GCM)
You need the AAD (seams to be 16 bytes here)
You need the input data (plaintext or ciphertext)

In encrypt you add the aad
System.arraycopy(aad, 0, encryptedBytes, plainBytes.length, 16);

in decrypt you do not use these data
cipher.processAADBytes(aad, 0, aad.length);

Please update your code, that no global variables are used.
May [16 byte AAD || 12 byte IV || ciphertext] be a good output for encrypt for you? At decrypt read aad, then iv, then perform decryption.
Use inputstream and outputstream for simple read and write.
